# MySQL update with sub select

Tags: mysql

I have a table lets call it table1, and the data in two of the columns has been destroyed.

Fortunately I have an old backup of the table.

In the old backup the values for the two columns in question are correct but the rest of the columns are outdated so I can't simply import the whole dump.

So instead I've imported it into another table which I'll call table2. Each record has an id which is the same in both tables.

So basically I need a query that will go through each record in table1 and update column1 and column2 with the corresponding values from table2.

Comment: Why don't you just create two columns in table1 and import data from corresponding columns of table2?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Original table is table1 and backup table is table2

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2, ...
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Multi-table update can be very useful http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Answer (score 25):

This will work on all flavours of SQL database:

```
update table1 t set
column1 = (select column1 from old_table where id = t.id),
column2 = (select column2 from old_table where id = t.id);
```

There's no need for any special/aggregate functions, because the id match will hit exactly one row.

Comment: Better answer if you want to work with totally different table structures.

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Murilo You *can* specify table `t` for update in FROM clause: See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/322625).

Comment: Yeah found out on my query i was referencing t on from table too which mysql doesnt allow it, but found a way around it by creating a temp table, this was really helpful anyway

Comment: Error 1093 indicates a subquery into the same table being updated.  The problem above is for two different tables, although someone might arrive here while googling for the syntax to use for self-referential updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1field = (SELECT MAX(table2.table2field) FROM table2 WHERE table1.table1field = table2.table2field)
```